# What are the food that can be eaten without much calories intake? (to combat hand-to-mouth pattern)

Tags: nutrition, calories

I like iceberg lettuce for eating and absorbing a lot of water...

What are the other foods I can eat endlessly without any calories intake?

Comment: You mean with lower calorie intake. By definition food contains calories.

Comment: Low calory intake. What I meant was - given the energy expendited in chewing and digesting it can be even **negative**... Something I can eat habitually without gaining weight / body fat.

Comment: Most vegetables are about as low in calories as you can get and still be eating real food. I seriously doubt it's possible to go negative.

Comment: There are no calorie-negative foods.

Comment: *"given the energy expendited in chewing and digesting"* - also raising hand to the mouth - do you think one can build muscles that way? http://www.discount-supplements.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/beer-muscles.jpg

Answer (score 1):

All food has calories; it is just a matter of what one's have the lowest.

Celery is high in water and low in calories, as is cabbage. For some more low calorie food ideas check out this website:

http://www.health.com/health/gallery/0,,20640804,00.html/view-all